# how to check for an existing data in sqlite database in ios

Tags: ios6, sqlite

Hi I am new to Sqlite Database environment.
I created a table with few fields and make 2 fields as UNIQUE. So, I have to show an alert to user while he/she inserts the duplicate data into table.
Can anyone tell me "How to check for an existing data before it can be inserted into the table in sqlite database"

Comment: check the count of corresponding table

Comment: i am not checking the table for knowing table is empty or not it for checking the data is existed or not before it is inserted into the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to query the input data entered by user and check whether it is present or not,

like fire the query `select count() from category where categoryName='usertext'`

obviously you know where to check the data
that is name of table(`category` in my case i.e. in above query) and column name(`categoryName`).

If count is more than zero,data is exist,you can alert user

else not exist.